# Journey Builder Ad Audience - Do new contacts get added to Facebook audience straight away?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, advertising-studio

We are getting started with Advertising Studio. We are looking at using the *Ad Audience* activity in Journey Builder.

I understand that Ad Studio will refresh an audience once per day at most. And I understand that upon refresh, any new contacts in the audience source in marketing cloud will then get pushed to Facebook for matching.

However, with regards to the journey builder *Ad Audience* activity, I'm wondering if:
1. Contact is added to audience source in MC, which then has to wait for a refresh to get pushed to Facebook for matching
OR
2. Contact is added to audience in MC and is instantly pushed to Facebook for matching?

In other words, if added to an audience via journey builder, will someone get an ad straight asap, or will the refresh need to take place first?

I couldn't find anything in the documentation to confirm one way or another.

Thanks

*(Side note - "ad-studio" or "advertising-studio" doesn't seem to be an available tag. If some one could create it that would be helpful*. Cheers.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I remember the audience activity simply creates a Facebook ad audience in Advertising Studio.

This audience has the same behaviour as a manually created one.

Your journey flow should therefore account for a 1 day "wait" period.

I haven't done it in a while so you should my answer.

Comment: Thanks Stephan, I have played a bit with it and it does seem to be working that way.